# How do I fix list index out of range on selenium web driver and empty list

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have been trying to open [this page](https://earthpol.com/map/safe.index.html), click a checkbox and leave it, however, when I try to get the element, either by XPath or class_name, I always get that there is no function click() for list, so what I did was type `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("leaflet-control-layers-selector")[0]`
and it wouldnt work, I then tried to print it to see what would come out, and "[ ]" was the output, an empty list, how am I supposed to work with one?
This is my code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://earthpol.com/map/safe.index.html')

# click radio button
# python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='mcmap']/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[3]/label[3]")
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("leaflet-control-layers-selector")[0]
print(python_button)
python_button.click()
```

EDIT
The checkbox incase you don't know dynmap is located on the left, click that icon with those isometric layers.

Answer (score 0):

It just means it didn't find any elements on the page with that classname. If there is only one `leaflet-control-layers-selector` button, do this instead:

```
python_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("leaflet-control-layers-selector")
python_button.click()
```

otherwise, you could enforce a wait condition (perhaps the element isn't visible yet)

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
wait_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'leaflet-control-layers-selector')))
wait_click.click()
```

Comment: i beleive there are more then one, how would i handle that?

Comment: I think that is a new question. But it would depend what you wanted to do. Just remove the bracket "[0]" and treat each index separately